# Missing some information in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'book'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.sg/s?k=Measuring+Tools+%26+Scales&i=home&crid=1011S67HHJSEW&sprefix=measuring+tools+%26+scales%2Chome%2C408&ref=nb_sb_noss']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]//tr')
        table={}
        for row in rows:
            brand = row.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'Brand')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get()
            asin = row.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'ASIN')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get().replace('\u200e',"")
            tub=response.xpath('//table[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]//tr')
            for col in tub:
                 Customer_Reviews= col.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'Customer Reviews')]/following-sibling::td//span/text()").get()
                 Best_SellersRank= col.xpath(" //th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'Best Sellers Rank')]/following-sibling::td//span/text()").get()
            table.update({'Brand':brand,'Asin':asin,'CustomerReview':Customer_Reviews,'BestSellerRank':Best_SellersRank})
        yield table
```

It will not give information of `customer review`,`best seller rank`

```
{'Brand': 'ENLOY ', 'Asin': ' B089ZN7MMW ', 'CustomerReview': '     ', 'BestSellerRank':' ' }
```

the page link is https://www.amazon.sg/Etekcity-Accurate-Measuring-Packages-Stainless/dp/B08BPB9T1N/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1011S67HHJSEW&keywords=Measuring%2BTools%2B%26%2BScales&qid=1643380692&s=home&sprefix=measuring%2Btools%2B%26%2Bscales%2Chome%2C408&sr=1-1&th=1

[image]

Comment: What text are you trying to capture exactly? "6,716 ratings" or "4.8 out of 5 stars"? both? Same question for Best Seller Rank. The way you are doing it now won't work. You are looping through each row of the table and then setting Customer_Reviews and Best_SellerRank each time, but each iteration is overwriting the last.

Comment: Also, scraping Amazon like this will not work in scale. It will block you very quickly and you also cannot scrape any attributes that are loaded via javascript.

Comment: I am trying to capture both  6,716 ratings" or "4.8 out of 5 stars and also scrape both the data in best seller rank can you help us